# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder.setSource

Tags: elasticsearch, pom.xml, spring-data-elasticsearch, parent-pom

I am trying to run the spring boot parent project which uses child project, which in turn uses project(ES project) which has elasticsearch dependencies and elasticsearch config bean for transport client.
The child project uses Spring Data ES repositories, which are enabled by a respective annotation in a project.
These are config annotations used in the child:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("package")
@EntityScan("package3")
@EnableJpaRepositories("package2")
// enables only es repos for current project, ESProject has this annotation for its packages respectively
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("package1")
```

The parent project has the only @SPringBootApplication on all packages of ES project and child one.

Parent pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>ChildProject</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        </dependency>
   <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

Child pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>ESProject </artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- exclusions -->
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ESProject Pom:

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>                    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>            
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

The parent project is a module of pom, which uses Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE.

When I run a parent project I am getting this. Clearly there are some dependencies conflicts but I can't quite figure out them.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; 

  nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder.setSource(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/mapping/put/PutMappingRequestBuilder;
```

Also, it's worth noting if I use ESProject in other projects I don't get this exception but I don't have Spring Data ES Repos in those projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pretty mix-up of Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch library versions in your setup. Let me try to visualize what we got:

```
Spring Boot 2.0.5 
  +- Elasticsearch                  5.6.11
  +- Data Kay.SR10
    +- Spring Data Elasticsearch    3.0.10
      +- Elasticsearch              5.5.0
```

Boot 2.0.5 pulls in ES 5.6.11 but at the same time via the Spring Data Kay releasetrain version 5.5.0 of ES and 3.0.10 of SDES (which is not nice but should work).

```
Spring Data Elasticsearch   3.1.1
  +- Elasticsearch          6.2.2
```

you define SDES 3.1.1 which relies on ES 6.2.2

```
Elasticsearch               6.4.1
```

finally you define the ES version to be 6.4.1

As for the error you see: The code that your application uses expects the following function to be available in the ES client libraries (using fully qualified names for the types):

```
org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder.setSource(java.lang.String)
```

This method existed in ES 5.5, but was already deprecated there (excerpt from the code):

```
    /**
     * The mapping source definition.
     * @deprecated use {@link #setSource(String, XContentType)}
     */
    @Deprecated
    public PutMappingRequestBuilder setSource(String mappingSource) {
        request.source(mappingSource);
        return this;
    }
```

in ES6 this method was removed and only the one with the additional `XContentType` parameter exists - which is used by SDES for this version.

So your application loads SDES 3.0 in combination with ES 6 libraries which cannot work.

So you should update your dependencies to a consistent version either using Boot 2.1 or 2.2 [check the version matrix here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#preface.versions)

Comment: It is really weird and non-obvious that this works like that. I would expect that if I use spring-data-elasticsearch all dependencies  will be used from there(apart from elasticsearch ones which I declare in pom). But instead spring data es somehow uses spring boots elasticsearch dependencies which must have been overriden. A little out of the scope, but I would appreciate it, is using spring boot of a higher version is the  only resolve in this case? Maybe there is some kind of fast workaround for this? Even bad one will suffice.

Comment: I can't update my version of spring boot for the whole project right now specifically first of all because the last version of spring data es introduces breaking changes, as you are surely aware of being its developer.

Comment: Funnily enough, ESProject itself being reused in other project doesn't introduce such problems though it probably must have as it also has Spring Boot parent through a chain of other parents.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.2 is not the latestversion, it uses Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x with Elasticsearch 6.8 client libs

Comment: As you are using the `NumberKeyedRepository` which was removed in Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2, you will need Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1, that should be with Spring Boot 2.1.