# Scroll finalizes successfully without scrolling through all records in ES

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a scroll based on the excerpt from these [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/#elasticsearch.scroll):

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .withIndices(INDEX_NAME)
    .withTypes(TYPE_NAME)
    .withFields("message")
    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10))
    .build();

Page<SampleEntity> scroll = elasticsearchTemplate.startScroll(1000, searchQuery, SampleEntity.class);

String scrollId = ((ScrolledPage) scroll).getScrollId();
List<SampleEntity> sampleEntities = new ArrayList<>();
while (scroll.hasContent()) {
    sampleEntities.addAll(scroll.getContent());
    scrollId = ((ScrolledPage) scroll).getScrollId();
    scroll = elasticsearchTemplate.continueScroll(scrollId, 1000, SampleEntity.class);
}
elasticsearchTemplate.clearScroll(scrollId);
```

I need to scroll through a huge dataset(more than 100 mil).

My scroll looks **exactly the same**(only my query and objects) as this excerpt.
But in startScroll and contrinueScroll I pass a different custom document class, which has much less fields than the document, which is used for indexing, but my query has filters so only several fields that match this another document which is used for the scroll are returned.

`getTotalElements()` scroll method returns correct number of all elements to be fetched.

Scroll loop finishes successfully but it scrolls only through 6% of the dataset.

Comment: anything in the logs? Can you access the logs of Elasticsearch?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I am going to try to do that if there are any.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I am struggling to find something, in particular, I checked logs for all nodes on each server but there is nothing during the hour when the scroll is finished in the app and almost nothing during the whole scroll, but I am not sure it has something to do with scroll though it might.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I forgot to mention - during the scroll `ERROR [elasticsearch[_client_][transport_client_boss][T#1]] org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils:183 - fatal error on the network layer` and OOME but the sxroll doesn't terminate and finished successfully.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I added logs, almost all I could find the relevant timespan, could you take a look? https://gist.github.com/UkrainianCitizen/ea0389adc069c678eae5e6b749920f0c

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution, but looking at your code, your are building a `List<SampleEntity>` that will eventually contain *all* your `SampleEntity`s. If one of these entities uses only 256 bytes, with more than 100mil, that would be t least 25GB memory. How much memory do you have available?

As for the server logs: Here it seems, that Elasticsearch is using up all it's memory as well, according to the garbage collection messages. What have you configured on these machines?

**Edit 25.07.2020**:

I have set up a test program with the following setup:

- local Elasticsearch 6.4.2
- Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.1.0 using transport client

I have created an index with 25 million entries, objects with an Long Id and one uuid as String. This put some strain on ES in regards to garbage collection, but completed.

Reading all entries (not aggregating the results in a list, but counting the returned records) with a matchAll query and a pageable of size 1000 ran without problems.

Using no pageable in the request (resulting in a request size of 10 per scroll request) put a heavy load on Elasticsearch and even more on the client process. But this request finished without problems as well, although running very, very, very slow. This creates heavy garbage collections in both the Elasticsearch and the client program.

So it seems that the code is correct, the problem lies in the page size, the default of 10 is way too less, I ran it successfully with up to 10000 (which is the maximum you can use without increasing `index.max_result_window`).

So you could try to increase the size of the pageable, but keep in mind, that collecting all these elements puts a heavy load on the memory consumption of your application.

Comment: There are 4 servers with 2 nodes on each, several nodes have 800 gigs of free disk memory, all others have 1 tb - 1.66 tb of free disk memory, most of the nodes have 10-14 gigs of heap memory, a few have more. I've put logs for all nodes for the timespan when the generation happened. Could you kindly explain what do you mean by `What have you configured on these machines?`?

Comment: how much memory is configured for Elasticsearch? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html

Comment: I see, so I answered how much heap memory is used, didn't make it clear, sry, maximum heap memory on all nodes is 31.81 gigs. Here is the full breakdown of used heap memory *1-1: used - 23* ; *1-2: used - 16* ; *2-1: used - 14* ; *2-2: used - 18* ; *3-1: used - 14* ; *3-2: used - 12* ; *4-1: used - 20* ; *4-2: used - 23* .

Comment: I'm no expert for the setup of an ES cluster, so I'm afraid I can't help you there. But for the application: Do you need to collect all 100mill objects in a list? What happens if you just do the scroll without collecting the data, just for a test call the scroll functions and count what you got. Does that finish properly?

Comment: which versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch and  Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287683/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-elasticsearch-action-admin-indices-mapping-put), please, `ESProject pom`. The version conflict is still in place though. I also was trying to find what is `withFields()` for but there is nothing about this in JavaDoc.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.